# Can you omit rowsize when making an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

In my notes about two dimensional arrays, it says you can define it without a row size but you need a column size. Is this a mistake by our professor? Because we later, in the same notes, it says you can define an array like this:

```
int [][] derparray = new int [4][];
```

It seems like it would be the other way around, no?

Comment: Which are the "rows" and which are the "columns" is an arbitrary choice of what each dimension represents. The point is, you need to define the size of all but the last dimension.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Not true.  `int [][][] a = new int[4][][]` is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at a 2-D matrix, the "row size" equals the "number of columns", and the "column size" is the "number of rows".

Doing something like this:

```
int [][] derparray = new int [4][5];
```

allocates an array of 4 elements, where each element is an array that contains 5 elements.  This in effect gives you a 2-D array with 4 rows and 5 columns.  Here, the "column size" is the number of rows, which is 4; and the "row size" is the number of columns, which is 5.

If you do this:

```
int [][] derparray = new int [4][];
```

4 is the number of rows.  However, *nothing* is allocated for each element.  Each element is set to `null`, but each elements can be set later to a one-dimensional `int[]` array.  The one-dimensional arrays don't have to be the same size for all rows.  So in this example, we *could* say that since the column size is the number of rows, then the column size is 4.  However, since this doesn't actually allocate any "columns", it seems rather odd to talk about a column size.  So I'd say no, your professor didn't get it backwards, but what he said was put in a rather confusing way.

Basically, I'd say that unless you actually allocate a matrix as in the first example, it's not a good idea to talk about "row size" or "column size".  Those terms aren't really meaningful.

**MORE:** The following is illegal in Java, because it doesn't make any sense:

```
int [][] derparray = new int [][4];
```

because a 2-D array is really an array of arrays.  In the `new int [4][]` example, this creates an array of 4 rows, but the array elements (the rows) don't yet contain anything.  This is fine, because you can set the array elements later.  But what would `new int [][4]` do?  It seems like it would create an array where each element is an array of 4 integers (the columns), but where would it put each element?  It can't create the array that holds all those elements, because you haven't told it how many elements to create.  Therefore, you can omit the "number of columns", but you can't omit the "number of rows".  I think that's what your professor meant by saying you can omit the row size but not the column size, but as I've explained above, the terms don't really make sense.

Comment: So could you make something like this: `int [][] derparray = new int [][4];`

Comment: @munchschair no, that's illegal.  See my edit.  The rule (if you don't have an initial aggregate) is that you can have one or more `[n]` that has an actual count in it, followed by zero or more `[]` with nothing in between the square brackets.  But you can't have a `[]` followed by an `[n]`.

Comment: So the initial bracket is an array and the brackets following it are arrays of that array. Which is why you can't have an array of no initial array. Do I have it right?

Comment: @munchschair Something like that, yes.